# Flow: check type of thenable

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a function that accepts either a thenable (an object that has a `then()` method; see the top of [MDN JavaScript docs: `Promise.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)) or something else:

```
function resolve<T>(value: {then: ()=>T}|T) {
    if (value && value.then) {
        console.log('thenable', value.then);
    } else {
        console.log('not thenable');
    }
}
```

[Try Flow demo](https://flow.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKYGc4BsBuqA8AKgHwAUOAhliKgFyIDeUAFqmPaQJQC8xhAvgB9CnRgChEkxDGCJyVGogBkSxJWqoAdCzaiGEqYYgJMWLVjgBzUgHIdYCgCMzNgDRqFW+5wDcByfyIqFjoqOKGRibY5la2YHBQiPZOLr7+iPxi-EA)

Flow complains when I access `value.then` in this `if` statement. I can fix it with `(value: any).then` but this looks hacky.

Can anyone recommend a good way to type-check this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question! This is something that the Flow team has been wrestling with over the last few weeks!

### What is the problem

```
if (value && value.then) {
  // What is the type of `value` here?
} else
```

Inside of that if statement, what is the type of `value`? If `T` is `string`, then it will be `{then: ()=>T}`, as you expect. But what if `T` is `{ then: string }`? For all we know, `T` might have a property named `then`!

### What is the Flow team doing to fix this?

- Adding exact object types. This problem comes from not knowing whether one branch of a union may or may not have a property. With exact types, you can tell Flow exactly which properties an object has.
- Allowing the `value.then` property check, and refining the type of `value.then` to `mixed`.

A lot of this work is already in master. You can check out flowtype.org/try, which currently runs off of master. [Your example on flowtype.org/try](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVUCuA7AxgFwEs5swAnAUwGc4YA3CgHgBUA+ACjoEMZMKAuMAG98ACwrZB7AJQBeVswC+AH2bThqMFrCEoYTjz5gAZMbDdeFAHRiJ6oZu1PcJGjGvwA5uwDkt7FwARu4+ADTmhtb+0gDcjlqKYBQwVBQaTs6utB5w3j7YcPhg-kEhsfFgiqiKQA)

Once this stuff lands (some comes in v0.31.0 and some in v0.32.0) we'll document and blog about it.

edit: adding more information

### 3 main problems

There are 3 general questions that we're working on resolving.

- When should we allow `value.then` in a conditional? If we only allow `value.then` when we're sure that `value` has a `then` property, then we can catch typos like `value.tehn`. However, idiomatic JavaScript often tests objects for properties that may or may not exist.
- What is the type of `value` if the conditional is true or false. In the provided example, `value` is a union type. It appears like the intention of `value && value.then` is to detect if the function is using the left branch of the union. However, Flow can't safely choose a branch, since T might have a `then` field.
- What is the type of `value.then` if the conditional is true or false. Again, `T` might be an object like `{ then: string }`, so `value.then` might be anything

### Our solutions

> When should we allow `value.then` in a conditional

We'll always allow `value.then`. This means we can't catch property name typos as easily, but it means we can support more idiomatic JavaScript. One of Flow's main tenets is that it works well with the JavaScript that people tend to write.

> What is the type of `value` if the conditional is true or false.

If Flow knows for certain that only one branch of the union type will work, it will refine the type of `value` to that branch. Otherwise, `value` won't be refined. Exact types will help with this

> What is the type of `value.then` if the conditional is true or false

If Flow knows for certain that only one branch of the union type will work, it will refine the type of `value.then` to the type of the `then` property on that branch. If Flow knows for certain that no branch has that property, it will error. Otherwise, it will use the type `mixed`. Exact types help with this too.

### What are exact types

`{ x: string }` is the type of an object with a property `x` which has the type `string`.

```
var example1: { x: string } = { x: 'hello' }; // This is ok
var example2: { x: string } = { x: 'hello', y: 123 }; // This is also ok
```

This is useful for idiomatic JavaScript, but makes it hard for Flow to say that an object type DOESN'T have a property. So we're adding exact types.

`{| x: string |}` is the type of an object with a property `x` which has the type `string` but no other properties.

```
var example1: {| x: string |} = { x: 'hello' }; // This is ok
var example2: {| x: string |} = { x: 'hello', y: 123 }; // Error! Extra property y!
```

This helps, because you can write something like this:

```
type Foo = {| x: string |} | {| y: string |};

function test(arg: Foo): string | void {
  if (arg.x) {
    return arg.x;
  }
}
```

Once we launch these, we'll document them! So keep your eyes peeled!

Comment: thanks. my example on flowtype is the same as the original one I posted. You say that with these new changes I will be able to specify exact types, but this example does not have anything new but it still type checks. Did I misunderstand what you said?

Comment: I wrote my answer in a bit of a rush, so I didn't provide clarifying examples, but I'll try and fix that soon.